# Video capture open cv c++ code won't work on my laptop || OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor

Tags: opencv

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It means that `cvtColor` expected an image with 3 or 4 channels but your supplied image isn't, it's possibly YUV which is 2 channels. You'll need to determine the the colour space prior to converting and then pass the correct conversion color code: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0

Comment: Maybe you can phrase a clear question? Also, it would help if you tell us bit more about your setup, what you are trying to achieve, and what you have already tried.

Comment: Ah, the daily `cvtColor` assert question :D `cap >> frame;` failed to grab a frame, so `frame` is an empty image. You don't test for that scenario, and `cvtColor` doesn't like being given empty images. (There's a very small chance the camera returns something else than BGR -- won't hurt validating that either).

Comment: try `VideoCapture cap(1);` Your default driver may not be loaded correctly